# Sorting Tables via Query Editor and Receiving Duplicate Rows

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sorting

Evening all (morning for some of us),

First off, I am new to SQL as you may be able to tell from previous posts. I am trying to teach myself and it's difficult, but fun and rewarding at the same time.

I am messing around with my existing tables that I created and I am trying to figure out how to combine two tables into one query, sort one column first by ascending order, and then another column by alphabetical order.

My Customer table consists of 4 rows, with 3 columns (Customer ID, Customer Name, CustomerAddressID) and my second table, Address consists of 4 rows and 5 columns (AddressID, Street, City, State, ZipCode)

I have tried a few ways to do this but I am running into some problems.

```
SELECT [CustomerName],[Street],[City],[State],[ZipCode]
FROM Customer,Address
ORDER BY ZipCode ASC, CustomerName;
```

The above code combines everything into one result, which is fantastic, but I end up with 16 rows. The first 4 rows show the CustomerName in Alphabetical order which is what I want. The rest of the columns however are all duplicates. I attached a screenshot of my two attempts to query the correct data. [image: This screenshot is the two attempts I have been messing with trying to get this to work]

Please note that I have Primary Keys set up as AddressID, CustomerID and a Foreign Key setup as the CustomerAddressID. I am not sure if these need to be included in my query to help sort the information.

I've had enough hitting my head against the wall trying to figure this out. I've consulted just about every guide I can find and I just can't seem to get this to work.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Jason

Edit** (Here is my original INSERT statements for the data)

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Address]
       ([AddressID]
       ,[Street]
       ,[City]
       ,[State]
       ,[ZipCode])
VALUES
       (1,'2400 Broadway','New York','NY',11201),
       (2,'320 21st Street','Atlanta','GA',30322),
       (3,'439 Skyline Blvd','Seattle','WA',98101),
       (4,'56 Park Avenue','Dallas','TX',75201);
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customer]
       ([CustomerID]
       ,[CustomerName]
       ,[CustomerAddressID])
VALUES
       (1,'Western Supply Co.',2),
       (2,'Jake Harper',4),
       (3,'Elizabeth Harper',1),
       (4,'Abacus Consulting',3);
GO
```

EDIT 2*

Thank you Ughai for the quick assistance. I played with it and figured it out. Works perfectly now:

```
SELECT Customer.CustomerName, Address.Street, Address.City, Address.State, Address.ZipCode
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN Address
ON Customer.CustomerAddressID=Address.AddressID
ORDER BY ZipCode ASC, CustomerName ASC;
```

Comment: I have a bit. I tried doing an Inner Join but realized I don't have a matching Column in either of my Tables.

Comment: The reason you are getting 16 rows because you are missing the join condition. `Customer.CustomerAddressID = Address.AddressID`. Also always use ANSI Standard Joins. use of `,` is depreciated.

Comment: Ughai, you sir/madam are amazing. Just redid my query from scratch, and it pulled everything perfectly. I added ORDER BY ZipCode ASC, CustomerName ASC; at the end of my query. It pulls the Zip Code in ascending order, but my CustomerName is not fully in order. I am assuming that is because the ZipCode ORDER request takes precedence?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. Your results will be sorted in `ZipCode` and for rows with the same `zipcode`, these rows will be then sorted on `CustomerName`.

Comment: Excellent. Glad I am finally picking everything up. Sometimes it takes a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote a query that simply does a cross join.
Try below query to get the proper result.

```
SELECT C.CustomerName, A.Street, A.City, A.State, A.ZipCpde 
FROM Customer C 
INNER JOIN Address A 
ON C.CustomerAddressID = A.AddressID 
ORDER BY A.ZipCode ASC, C.CustomerNAme;
```

When you want to get the result from two or more tables you always use JOIN.
JOIN Clause always returns the concise result.

Comment: Thank you. I just did basically the same thing you just did. I was playing around with Join earlier but misunderstood the description. I thought that I had to have a matching column and was unaware I could set the CustomerAddressID (foreign key) equal to AddressID (primary key). Had I known this about 5 hours ago...sigh. Thank you all very much. Frigging love SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT c.[CustomerName],a.[Street],a.[City],a.[State],a.[ZipCode]
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN Address a ON a.AddressID = c.CustomerAddressID
ORDER BY a.ZipCode ASC, c.CustomerName;
```